# Best learning automata reinforcement schema for solving grid world,help me

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have a **gridworld puzzel** , an agent and Target , I want find best path for reaching Target by agent.

gridworld example(with S as start point, G as goal point and black cells as cliffs):
[image]

Comment: This needs more information. Usually a grid world is a toy problem used to teach reinforcement learning (and RL is not really the best way to solve it). Could you clarify what you are trying to learn, and where you are stuck?

Comment: gridworld can be complicated problem when you want have some innovation jobs , my target is using a non linear method of learning automata , some articles are available and im researching about that

Comment: If you want help with understanding the articles, and implement something from them, then please quote relevant parts of the articles where you are stuck, and link them for context. Otherwise you appear to be asking "how to solve gridworld" without any context (and without enough information to actually work on a solution, such as the reward scheme, although I can guess). Use [edit] to provide details.